# FULLCALENDAR: How to disable prev button and only be able to see current month and the next?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I downloaded: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

Does somebody know how i can disable the prev button, so you can only see the current month and how i can limit the next button, so you can only see one next month?

I put this in the head:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.setDate();
    var m = date.setMonth();
    var y = date.setFullYear();

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        editable: true,
        events: [
            {
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the prev/next button by just adding 'fc-state-disabled' class.

e.g.

```
//disballing prev button
 $(".fc-button-prev").addClass('fc-state-disabled');
```

Also if you just want to allow to show only next month on clicking on next button then add following code.

```
function checkNext(e) {
        if (isNextallowed == true) {
            isNextallowed = false;
            return true;
        } else {
            $(".fc-button-next").addClass('fc-state-disabled');
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }

$(".fc-button-next").on("click", checkNext);
$(".fc-button-next .fc-text-arrow").on("click", checkNext)
```

Checkout this [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skuj8/6/)

Answer (score 0):

try -

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    editable: true,
    header : {
         left : 'next today'
    }
 });
```

You can also refer to the documentation of the fullCalendar API to get more insight into how it works and other possible options. Refer - [Full Calendar from Adam Arshaw](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my simple solution.

Place this code in the renderView function (around line 368 in version 1.5.4)) before ignoreWindowResize--; near the end of the function.

```
var lammCurrentDate = new Date();
var lammMinDate = new Date( lammCurrentDate.getFullYear(), lammCurrentDate.getMonth(), 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
if (currentView.start <= lammMinDate){
    header.disableButton('prev');
} else {
    header.enableButton('prev');
}
```